# Limit in the definition of derivatives is unique.

Tags: calculus, general-topology, manifolds, differential-topology

We know by first principle derivatives of function f at 'a' is given by 
f'(a)=limh→0[(f(a+h)-f(a))/h] exists...........(1)
From our basic calculas it is also known that limit is unique.we also know that in a non Hausdorff space limit of a function need not be unique ,now my question is if f is differentiable then whether limit at right hand side is going to be unique no matter which topology we take.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derivatives make no sense in arbitrary topological spaces, so we are in no danger of running into that problem. Say $f\colon X\rightarrow Y$ is a map between topological spaces. Then what does the quotient
$$\frac{f(a+h) - f(a)}{h}$$
even mean? You are adding elements of $X$. This operation is not available in some arbitrary topological space. Then you subtract $f(a)$ from $f(a+h)$ and divide by $h$. Again, these operations are not available in the general context of topological spaces. Note also that $h$ appears both as in conjunction with elements of $X$ and elements in $Y$, so wherever $h$ comes from, this set must operate on both $X$ and $Y$. To define the derivative you must impose some sort of algebraic structure on $X$ and $Y$. Moreover, for the derivative to be *meaningful*, the algebraic structure on $X$ and $Y$ must also be meaningful. This brings us all the way to Euclidean spaces and their more immediate generalizations (e.g. normed linear spaces).

Comment: $h$ need not be an element of $X$ as long as the operation $+$ is defined at least for the element $h$ and all elements of $X$, such that $a\in X\implies a+h\in X$. Likewise, $h$ need not be an element of $Y$ as long as the operation $\frac{\cdot}{\cdot}$ is defined at least for $h$ and all elements of $Y$ (assuming that $\forall a,b\in.Y a-b\in Y$).

Comment: Sure! Nevertheless, I was not trying to present a formal argument about the most general case. This is why I try to stress whether it is meaningful to define the derivative. The question seems to imply that whoever is asking it feels that it is *always* meaningful.

Comment: On second thought, I will change it. Thanks for the tip